# How to use tab control for Manipulate when the number of options exceeds 5?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, interface

I have 2 `Manipulate` as below,

```
Manipulate[plot[i], {i, Range[5]}]
Manipulate[plot[i], {i, Range[6]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the 1st one uses tab as control, while the 2nd one uses a pop-up menu as control, since the number of options exceeds 5.

How can I force the `Range[6]` one to use tab?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the type of control as input to override the default ones:

```
Manipulate[plot[i], {i, Range[10], SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Manipulate[plot[i], {i, Range[10], ControlType -> SetterBar}] (* or *)
Manipulate[plot[i], Control[{i, Range[10], SetterBar}]]
```

> same  picture